# Hanging token from user input is not allowing me to proceed in my program

Tags: java

My program is not allowing me to enter user input if i do not enter a number and i want to go through the program again, it think its due to a hanging token somewhere but i cannot seem to find it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LessonTwo {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char answer = ' ';
        do {
            System.out.print("Your favorite number: "); 
            if (userInput.hasNextInt()) {
                int numberEntered = userInput.nextInt();
                userInput.nextLine();

                System.out.println("You entered " + numberEntered);

                int numEnteredTimes2 = numberEntered + numberEntered;
                System.out.println(numberEntered + " + " + numberEntered
                        + " = " + numEnteredTimes2);

                int numEnteredMinus2 = numberEntered - 2;
                System.out.println(numberEntered + " - 2 " + " = "
                        + numEnteredMinus2);

                int numEnteredTimesSelf = numberEntered * numberEntered;
                System.out.println(numberEntered + " * " + numberEntered
                        + " = " + numEnteredTimesSelf);

                double numEnteredDivide2 = (double) numberEntered / 2;
                System.out.println(numberEntered + " / 2 " + " = "
                        + numEnteredDivide2);

                int numEnteredRemainder = numberEntered % 2;
                System.out.println(numberEntered + " % 2 " + " = "
                        + numEnteredRemainder);

                numberEntered += 2; // *= /= %= Also work
                numberEntered -= 2;

                numberEntered++;
                numberEntered--;

                int numEnteredABS = Math.abs(numberEntered); // Returns the
                int whichIsBigger = Math.max(5, 7);
                int whichIsSmaller = Math.min(5, 7);

                double numSqrt = Math.sqrt(5.23);

                int numCeiling = (int) Math.ceil(5.23);
                System.out.println("Ceiling: " + numCeiling);

                int numFloor = (int) Math.floor(5.23);
                System.out.println("Floor: " + numFloor);

                int numRound = (int) Math.round(5.23);
                System.out.println("Rounded: " + numRound);

                int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                System.out.println("A random number " + randomNumber);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry you must enter an integer");
            }
            System.out.print("Would you like to try again? ");

            answer = userInput.next().charAt(0);

        }while(Character.toUpperCase(answer) == 'Y');
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right you need to **consume** the characters first after the user inputted `character` in the `nextInt` before allowing the user to input data again

just add this in your else block and it will work:

```
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry you must enter an integer");
        userInput.nextLine(); //will consume the character that was inputted in the `nextInt`

    }
```

**EDIT:**

change this:

```
answer = userInput.next().charAt(0);
```

to:

```
answer = userInput.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Comment: I am using eclipse and I have tried this but it still doesn't allow me to enter input after i don't enter a number.

Comment: @Purpl3Paul I just tried it and it does let me input after I put characters.

Comment: if you enter in a number the first time and then enter Y and then the second time enter in a character 'h' for example it will not let you enter in Y or N if you want to continue